# Disable dates in bootstrap datepicker

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

as the title says, I would like to disable specific dates from a bootstrap datepicker (v4.6).Is there a way to do so? I've already tried to add some properties to it by doing

```
$('#input_date').datepicker('option', 'minDate', '2022-02-10');
```

without success (it actually creates a new jquery UI datepicker which I don't want).

Comment: Please read the documentation: https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#datesdisabled

Comment: Which datepicker? There is more than one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As posted in the comment to your answer, you can find the required options here: https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#datesdisabled

Something like:

```js
$('#input_date').datepicker({
  'minDate': '2022-02-10',
  'datesDisabled': [
     new Date(2021, 03, 25),
     "03/25/2021 00:00"
   ]
});
```

Also an answer: [Bootstrap datetimepicker datesDisabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40956986/bootstrap-datetimepicker-datesdisabled)

Comment: Updated with more relevant info